# Magnifier for Konva Layers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, konvajs

I have some konva shapes on top of an image, I want to develop a magnifier to show a part of the konva stage. What is the proper way to do it? The challenge is that I should draw all layers including the image layer and shapes on top of it in the magnifier box. I use Vue Konvajs.

Comment: What is "magnifier box"? Do you want to just show zoomed part of the stage somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the zoomed part of the stage with all its layers in somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Just like this: https://github.com/jy1989/canvas.magnifier.js
But I have two(or more) layers, one is a konva image layer and the other layer is konva shapes on top of the image.

Comment: you can try to use just one layer to use that library. Or you can try something like this: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Stage_Preview.html but instead of zoom out for preview your need to zoom it for magnifier.